# Placing a widget inside a custom widget with custom itemView yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create a custom widget named 'IssueList' which will extend 'ListView'.

```
<?php
namespace frontend\components;

use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\widgets\ListView;

class IssueList extends Widget{
public $dataProvider;


public function init(){
    parent::init();
}
public function run(){
    return ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $this->dataProvider,
        'itemOptions' => [
            'class' => 'item issue-item'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'issue_list'
        ],
        'itemView' => '_issueListView',
        'layout' => '{items}{pager}',
    ]);

}

}?>
```

However the ListView has a custom itemView. When rendering the widget I get this error

The view file does not exist:

/var/www/clients/client1/web1/frontend/views/comments/_issueListView.php

Its obviously looking in the wrong directory, how do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

`itemView` is passed to [yii\base\View render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#render%28%29-detail) which is responsible for rendering view. So you can change view path how you want, using aliases if needed:

> Renders a view.
>
> The view to be rendered can be specified in one of the following
>   formats:
>
> - path alias (e.g. "@app/views/site/index");
> - absolute path within application (e.g. "//site/index"): the view name starts with double slashes. The actual view file will be looked
>     for under the view path of the application.
> - absolute path within current module (e.g. "/site/index"): the view name starts with a single slash. The actual view file will be looked
>     for under the view path of the current module.
> - relative view (e.g. "index"): the view name does not start with @ or /. The corresponding view file will be looked for under the view path
>     of the view $context. If $context is not given, it will be looked for
>     under the directory containing the view currently being rendered
>     (i.e., this happens when rendering a view within another view).

If you want it to be more dynamic, you can pass closure to `itemView` with the following signature:

```
function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
    ...
}
```

See docs for `itemView` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$itemView-detail).

Besides the API Documentation, rendering views and specifying paths is described in official docs in [Views (Rendering Views)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#rendering-views) section.